# java app connecting to mysql db - Unknown packet type 0x4a

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a third party application that I am installing to my Windows XP machine. It is a Java application that uses Hibernate as a backend and allows connection to a MySQL database via JDBC.

The application has a configuration wizard as well as a config file. I have in my config file the following:

```
test.hibernate.connection.driver_class = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
test.hibernate.connection.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
test.hibernate.connection.username = (username)
test.hibernate.connection.password = (password)
test.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
test.hibernate.current_session_context_class = thread
```

The error I get when I run the configuration wizard with these settings is:
I/O Error: Unknown packet type 0x4a

All I know about this cryptic error is that it is likely a SQLException thrown by the com.mysql.jdbc.Driver, and it has something to do with TDS codes (here is a resource I found: http://www.freetds.org/tds.html).

I have access to the java app's source code but I can't build a new executable due to needing a license for one of the dependencies. However, if it would help to post some of that please let me know.

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Caliris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mysql driver that the app uses might not be compatible with the MySQL installed.

Comment: The app is using MySQL Connector/J version 5.1.12. I tried installing a previous version, downgrading from Mysql 5.5 to 5.1. In fact I downloaded the exact version I saw in the directions that came with this third party software - 5.1.47. Unfortunately the error is still there, though it's now a different packet: I/O Error - Unknown packet type 0x3e.

Comment: I never did discover the problem but this answer did inspire me to do some useful research.